# Change color of text object using formula in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]I want to change the color of the text in text object using formula in Crystal Report.
I tried like

```
If {mnth_ttx.weight}>0 Then
  crRed;
```

But the color is not changing at run time.
I wrote this condition under formula edit of *weight*  text object. But not working.
How to change the color of a text using formula

Comment: Will you post a picture of your report with data (specifically this column)?  Please redact/eliminate any sensitive data.

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click field: select `Format Field...`
2. Select `Font` tab, then click `conditional-formula` button to the right of the color picker
3. Enter this formula: `If {mnth_ttx.weight}>0 Then crRed Else crBlack`

Comment: I did exactly these steps already but nothing reflecting in the report.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click field: select Format Field.
2. select font tab.
3. click on the X+2 box directly to the right of the  color picker. The Formula Editor will open.
4. Enter this formula:

   ```
   If {mnth_ttx.weight}>0 
     Then crRed 
   Else crBlack
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tried-and-true "currentfieldvalue" evaluation.

1. Right click on your element and hit "Format Field"
2. In the Font tab, click on the edit button for "Color".
3. Enter this:

   ```
   if currentfieldvalue > 0 then crRed else crBlack
   ```
4. That's all she wrote

Answer (score 0):

You can create a more advanced format using html
First text field need to set the TextFormat property as crHTMLText
With this the text field will interpret the html after being assigned in the formula you can put the following

```
if {?PARAMETER}=3 then    
If not IsNull ({TABLE.FIELD1}) Then
   "<p><b><font color='#00559c'>" & {TABLE2.FIELD1} & "</font></b></p>" & {TABLE2.FIELD2} & ": " & {TABLE2.FIELD2}
Else
    "<p><b><font color='#00559c'>" & {TABLE2.FIELD1} & "</font></b></p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if x> 0 then
formula= color(159,255,159)
else 
formula = crRed
end if
```

'The values in the color(159,255,159) are color(red, green, blue).  These are the numbers that you will see when you create a custom color.

Answer (score 0):

Right click field
1. Select format object
2. Goto Border
3. Select Background Colorado
4. Click OK.

That's it. You are done!