# highlight particular row in Crystal Report based on column value C#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

how to highlight particular row in Crystal Report based on column value C#.net

After Generate Report I want to Highlight all the Records with Value in the column (Assume "Status") values="OK"

If there is a way to do this using  in C#.NET

Comment: You want to just highlight all the columns with the value with ok?.. do you want to pass a parameter to the report from your c # code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your crstal report right click the relevant field object you want to highlight and select the "Format Field.." option. In the border tab tick the "Background" check box and you can enter a condition to select the background color of the field. The script looks something like bellow.

(comment: {user1.username} --> user1 is the table and username is my column.)

if {user1.username}='ok' then 
crGreen

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula in order to change text properties as shown in here:
[Change color of text object using formula in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125041/change-color-of-text-object-using-formula-in-crystal-reports)

Edit:

To highlight you can go to the borders tab and activate the background color checkbox. Then add the formula to add any check you want to do before.

If you want to highlight all the row you can always apply same formula to all fields in the row